# Add continuation block to method

Tags: objective-c

I have a singleton that displays status messages:

```
+ (FFStatusDisplay*) sharedInstance
{
    static FFStatusDisplay* sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, 
    ^{
        sharedInstance = [[FFStatusDisplay alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void) showStatus:(NSString*)message Timeout:(float)timeout Controller:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    if (![self isDisplaying])
    {
        [self setIsDisplaying:YES];
        [self setStatusAlert:[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]];

        [controller presentViewController:[self statusAlert] animated:YES completion:
        ^{
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(timerExpired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)timerExpired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [[self statusAlert] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self setStatusAlert:nil];
    [self setIsDisplaying:NO];
}
```

I would like to modify showStatus so that I can optionally call it with a completion block that executes after the message is removed by the timer. I think the declaration should be something like this:

```
- (void) showStatus:(NSString*)message Timeout:(float)timeout Controller:(UIViewController*)controller withBlock:(nullable id (^)(void))block;
```

But I don't know how to call the block in the body of the implementation. What I've been trying isn't right:

```
{
    if (![self isDisplaying])
    {
        [self setIsDisplaying:YES];
        [self setStatusAlert:[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]];

        [controller presentViewController:[self statusAlert] animated:YES completion:
        ^{
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(timerExpired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }];
    }

    block;  //this isn't right
}
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, you call a block like a C function:

```
block();
```

That being said, if you want it to fire after your timer has fired, you'll need to add some mechanism to hang onto the block and call it from your `timerExpired:` method